# When is it profitable to use the 'stock all' button?

Tags: tiny-tower

In Tiny Tower (iOS app), there is an option to 'stock all' to stock all your floors. This restocks any floor with stock that has already been ordered and is ready to be delivered, and reorders more stock if applicable.

Fortunately, this option does not require any bux. My tower is 50 floors tall, so this option usually costs me 5-12k coins, depending on the situation. When my tower is *completely* stocked, I make around 1500 coins/min, but my tower is rarely ever 100% stocked. I've started using this option because if I restock by hand it can take me up to 10min sometimes.

However, I only want to continue this option if it is reasonably profitable. I don't want to make only ~18k coins and then have to pay 12k to restock. At what level does this option become more viable, if any? Is there a good strategy for using the feature, or should I avoid it all together?

Comment: Its a time saver. I don't remember how much of a premium it costs to purchase stock for a floor, but to stock a floor after the time is up (and the symbol is available) it costs 10 coins. Two biggest downsides are that you can't pick what gets stocked (always cheapest) and you get less for the fully stocked bonus